# WPF MVVM как сделать свойство анонимного типа

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Мне нужно в свойство пихать результат выборки:

```
var s = db.Marks.Where(x => x.NameAttestation == SelectedMark).First();
VerstatOperatorsMarks = from f in db.VerstatOperators
                        select new
                        {
                             FullName = f.FullName,
                             OC1 = s.OC1,
                             // много полей
                        };
```

VerstatOperatorsMarks и есть мое свойство, но как мне сделать его анонимного типа что бы спокойно прибиндиться?

Comment: Используйте 'object'. Либо заведите подходящий тип.

Comment: Т.е. в `VerstatOperatorsMarks` у вас коллекция, но тип элементов заранее неизвестен?

Comment: @Андрей именно так

Comment: @Vlad: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @Vlad Уже пробывал заводить класс в котором поля точно такие же как и те что я выбираю, но писало ошибку что невозможно преобразовать, сделал как вы написали но тоже пишет ошибку object что то не нравить, но она вылетает только когда уже в запущеной программе, я то уже решил проблему другим способом, немного съехал от mvvm

Comment: @MaximKoylo: Ну так вы бы исправили ту ошибку, а не меняли бы полностью всё. Это всё равно, как если бы вы на машине заехали в тупик, и после этого решили сменить марку машины.

Comment: @VladD я то согласен, но у меня времени нету на рассусоливание ошибок, срочный проект

Comment: @MaximKoylo, а какие действия потом будут производиться с `VerstatOperatorsMarks`? Вставка/удаление/изменение элементов? Или только отображение?

Comment: @Андрей отображение, просто вывод по разным параметрам

Comment: @MaximKoylo, ну тогда пробуйте просто `IEnumerable` использовать или `IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: @Андрей та пробывал но писало ошибку при запуске окна в логах что то типо не удалось преобразовать из object, окно даже не открывалось хотя ошибки и не вылазило

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том что вижуалка писала в логах

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Но как такову ошибку не выбрасывало. Вижуалка словно пропускает это исключение, что бы посмотреть содержание этой ошибки нужно скопировать *System.NotSupportedException* и вставить в поле *Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings*, затем выбрать это исключение в предложеных вариантих. Запускаем откладку и радуемся полученому Exception.

В даном примере необходимо было привести результат запроса ToList

```
var s = db.Marks.Where(x => x.NameAttestation == SelectedMark).First();
VerstatOperatorsMarks = (from f in db.VerstatOperators
                         select new
                         {
                              FullName = f.FullName,
                              OC1 = s.OC1,
                              // много полей
                         }).ToList();
```

И соответственно *VerstatOperatorsMarks* задать тип как *IEnumerable<\object>*